# Total Texture memory size iOS / OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

My team is running into an issue where the amount of texture memory allocated via the `glTexImage2D` is high enough that it crashes the app ( at about 400 MB for iPhone 5). We're taking steps to minimize the texture allocation ( via compression, using fewer bits/channel and doing procedural shaders for VFX etc).

Since the app crashed on `glTexImage2D`, I felt like, it's running out of `texture memory` (as against virtual memory). Is there any documentation/guideline on the recommended texture memory usage by an app (not just [optimize your texture memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW1)) .

AFAIK on iOS devices ( and many Android devices) there's no dedicated VRAM and our app process is still well within the virtual memory limit. Is this some how related to the size of physical RAM ? My searches so far has resulted only in info on max texture size and tricks for optimizing texture usage and such. Any information is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think texture data can use a virtual memory and I can not even see that to be of any use at all, they are designed for speed. If you trully need so much texture data in memory you most likely hit the device cap but then again you might want to rethink if you DO need al that data there at all. Since the virtual memory would use a hard disc and then copy the data to memory when needed you could simply drop the raw RGBA data into some file representing a single texture data, then you can have a very quick texture loading from that file..

Comment: @MaticOblak I understand that I shouldn't overload the device memory with texture data. I just want to know how the limit is decided, so that I can make a more meaningful decision on my texture optimization techniques.

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no such thing as meaningful anymore at least not for the iOS. Your application can be killed even due to memory spikes, not only memory consumption if I remember correctly. The memory itself if shared with the GPU on these devices so only the overall amount counts. Your application is generally in its own sandbox and if you are losing free memory other apps might get killed if quick enough to gain more memory... So kindof try to keep below 50% of overall memory consumption, everything above is very dangerous